# Expo build is failing for production managed flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have an app using Expo sdk 49 that was working well until now. Development builds are working but production ones fails with the following unknown error:

```
$ set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ./myapp.xcworkspace -scheme myapp -configuration Release -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2024-03-06/myapp\ 2024-03-06\ 09.09.18.xcarchive archive | tee /Users/expo/workingdir/logs/myapp-myapp.log > /dev/null
▸ 2024-03-06 09:09:18.968 xcodebuild[2224:8988] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
⚠️  Script has ambiguous dependencies causing it to run on every build.
   To fix, go to: Xcode » myapp/myapp » Build Phases » 'Start Packager'
   Either: Uncheck "Based on dependency analysis", or select output files to trigger the script
⚠️  Script has ambiguous dependencies causing it to run on every build.
   To fix, go to: Xcode » myapp/myapp » Build Phases » 'Bundle React Native code and images'
   Either: Uncheck "Based on dependency analysis", or select output files to trigger the script
▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
2024-03-06 09:09:18.968 xcodebuild[2224:8988] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this or how to debug this ?

I did try to update all dependencies and fix all the issues. Expo doctor gives me everything is clear.